# Correct way of updating npm packages in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, webpack

I find various different approaches to updating packages using node. I am trying to update using the `package.json` packages in Visual Studio 2017 Community, when using their SPA Angular site.

Can anyone confirm the 'correct way' of doing this.

For example, I am trying to update to bootstrap v4 on this project. So i have changed the entry in the `package.json' to be;

`"bootstrap": "4.0.0",`

I have then tried the following;

1. Right-clicking package.json -> restore packages (this then runs a background task I can see this from the icon in the bottom left hand corner of the screen) and get 'Installing Packages Complete' once the task has run. 
   (Does this invoke npm update?)
2. I have also tried running the cmd `npm update --save/--save-dev1 in the package command console (I get the same response as above regarding a background task being run and then completed).

I assume the packages will be downloaded and stored in the node_modules folder in the project directory? In which case it appears the packages are not updating? As I have navigated to the node_module/bootstrap and when I look at the .js in the dist folder of the package it is still referencing 3.3.7?

I have tried deleting the entire contents of the node_modules folder and then the 2 above commands (which does repopulate, but with the same modules??).

Also to add if I navigate (in the solution explorer) to depedencies -> npm 3.3.7 of bootstrap is referenced here also.

I am also attempting to update angular to v6 as well, again unsuccessfully and v4 is still referenced everywhere (even though the package.json is updated.)

I am running the standard template for core 2 with angular 4 spa with Visusal Studio 2017 community edition.

Can someone explain the process and what I am doing wrong here please?

**Edit - Update**

I have managed to get singular packages to update, by right clicking the package in the solution explorer under dependencies -> npm -> .

this then runs another background task, but it then updates the package to match that what is in the package.json file?

It works at least, but surely there must be an easier way??

Comment: Open console, run `npm i -g npm-check-updates`, go to work directory and run `ncu -a` and enjoy

Comment: @botika ok so is the visual studio implementation buggy or broken? run what from the console?

Comment: Sorry, before I press enter before time. You already have a solution to update npm package.json. Remember install after

Comment: This is the issue. I have updated the package.json. But when I right click packages.json in the solution explorer and select update packages. The package is being installed is not the one reflected in my package.json. Could it be caching something somewhere??

Comment: you can run `npm install`. For clean npm cache `npm -f cache clear` but no need. Manage npm package by `npm` or `yarn` commands